# How to make a list horizontal scrollable

Tags: android-layout, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter

I'm using a CursorAdapter to display bitmaps from a ContentProvider in my ListFragment. The list is vertical scrollable by default. How can I make it horizontal scrollable instead of vertical scrollable e.g. in case of landscape layout?

Answer (score 0):

I find a list horizontal scrollable here http://www.dev-smart.com/?p=34 Let me know if this helps...